# Personalized URLs in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud

I know there are a couple questions about this but I am still confused so thought I'd ask.  This is my scenario - I want to send a cloud pages link/form to contacts through Marketing Cloud where they can check off a field "remove me from further emails".  Contacts that complete the form enter a journey where if they check off this field, the journey generates a task for me to go to their contact in Salesforce and uncheck some custom fields we've set up.

I want the task to link to the contact in Salesforce so I know that somehow I can personalize the URL of the Cloud Page via Salesforce ID but I'm unclear exactly how to do this.  I am just unclear how if someone fills out the form and enters a journey and a data extension, how the system will know who that contact is in Salesforce.

Please note I'm not a developer so please be very basic and simplistic in answering.  I won't be offended :)

Answer (score 1):

If the Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud is integrated you can use [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject Ampscript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm), so you don't need to update the data in Salesforce manually and instead it is done when someone submits the form.

Your setup should be something like:
Have a single form, pass in a unique identifier into the page, this could be email address or subscriberKey (Assuming the link to the page is in a email)

You can look up the SF ID using email address either in the Synchronised Data extension using Ampscript or Directly from SF using [Retrieve Salesforce Objects Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)

Once you have the SalesforceID you can update a field as described above using the UpdateSalesforceObject function.